# Targeting active / current_page_item in Wordpress menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, class

I am trying to make a link in my menu have an active state whilst on the correct page. Targeting the class `.current_page_item` has no effect as this is overridden by `.sidebar-primary a`.

So far I have added some classes to the menu items, `.nav-sidebar` and also inserted some php in my functions.php file to add the class `.active` to the current menu item. You would think that should cover it. Doing this has worked to a fashion.

```
<li id="menu-item-210" class="nav-sidebar menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-210 active "><a href="http://localhost/graham-every/" itemprop="url">Graham Every Ltd</a></li>
```

As you can see, `.nav-sidebar` and `.active` are available classes. However, using the  following CSS works, but does not change the font colour.

```
.nav-sidebar.active {
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #395CAC;
display: block;
padding: 7px;
}
```

This seems to be because it is simply overruled by the `.sidebar-primary a` class.

I have tried all sorts of combinations to target the active state without success, currently

```
.sidebar.sidebar-primary.widget-area a .nav-sidebar.active {
color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```css
.sidebar-content .sidebar-primary {
  width: 270px;
}
.sidebar.widget-area .widget {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.sidebar-primary,
.sidebar-secondary,
#ez-home-sidebar {
  color: #395CAC;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.sidebar.widget-area ol,
.sidebar.widget-area ul,
.sidebar.widget-area .textwidget,
.sidebar.widget-area .widget_tag_cloud div div,
.sidebar.widget-area .author-bio-widget,
.sidebar.widget-area .featuredpage .page,
.sidebar.widget-area .featuredpost .post {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 30px;
}
.sidebar.widget-area ul li {
  border-bottom: 0px solid #DDDDDD;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.sidebar-primary a,
.sidebar-primary a:visited,
.sidebar-secondary a,
.sidebar-secondary a:visited,
#ez-home-sidebar a,
#ez-home-sidebar a:visited {
  color: #395CAC;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*--- PRIMARY MENU ---*/

.nav-sidebar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.nav-sidebar a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #688bc9;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
}
.nav-sidebar.active {
  background-color: #395CAC;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
}
.sidebar.sidebar-primary.widget-area a .nav-sidebar.active {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
ul.sub-menu.nav-sidebar-sub {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}
/*--- END PRIMARY MENU ---*/
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="Primary Sidebar" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">
  <section id="nav_menu-7" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
    <div class="widget-wrap">
      <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-210" class="nav-sidebar menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-210 active "><a href="http://localhost/graham-every/" itemprop="url">Graham Every Ltd</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you want to highlight the ID which has "current-menu-item" so current page link is highlighted. In order to do so, write your css for that like below.

```
    .sidebar .menu li.current-menu-item
    {
    Your CSS here followed by !important without space (e.g. font-weight:600!important)
    }
```

Try this

Regards
Manoj Soni